# Google Analytics - Exclude All Parameters Except One

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I'm trying to set up an exclude filter in Google Analytics to exclude all query parameters but one.

I've found that expression to exclude all URL parameters

```
^[^?]+(\?.*)
```

But I can't find any way to modify it in order to exclude all parameters **except** "?q=".
Does anyone have any ideas on how I could achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: The `[?&]$` pattern does not match a `?` in `?q=`. If you need to match it, use `[?&]($|q=)`

Comment: Apologies, I copied the wrong expression, the one I found is    ^[^?]+(\?.*)

Comment: Try [`^[^?]+(\?(q[^=]|[^q]=|[^q][^=]).*)`](https://regex101.com/r/nI0nW9/1). If you say it does not work, please explain why, what is wrongly matched, and what should be matched.

Comment: Thanks it seems to work adding /gm but don't think that works with Google Analytics. Is this the only way to get this worked ?

Comment: The `/gm` modifiers are  for demo only. `/g` means find multiple matches, `/m` makes the `^` match at the beginning of a line, not the beginning of a string. You do not need the modifiers in GA at all.

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew, I'll try that. What about http://ggg.com/index.php?q=word&r=anotherword for instance ? It won't exclude "r=anotherword" will it ?

Comment: The whole URL won't get matched, `r=anotherword` won't be a match. I guess that means *excluded*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In GA, the RE2 engine is used, and it does not support lookaheads. Thus, the only way to make "exclusion" work is by using alternations with negated character classes.

Use

```
^[^?]+(\?(q[^=]|[^q]=|[^q][^=]).*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nI0nW9/1).

The regex means:

- `^` - match the start of the string
- `[^?]+` - match 1 or more characters other than a `?`
- `(\?(q[^=]|[^q]=|[^q][^=]).*)` - Group 1:

  - `\?` - one literal `?`
  - `(q[^=]|[^q]=|[^q][^=])` - Group matching either `q` + any character but a `=`, or any character but a `q` followed with a `=`, or any character but a `q` followed by any character but a `=`
  - `.*` - any characters but a newline up to the end of the string.